# how to use mysql event scheduler to backup logs?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I am storing my sql operation logs in a table sync_logger, and I want to save these logs to regular file periodically. In order to do so, I tried to create a event scheduler. but I always get following error at select statement.

```
MariaDB [sync]> DELIMITER !!
MariaDB [sync]> CREATE EVENT IF NOT EXISTS write_to_log_event
    -> ON SCHEDULE
    -> EVERY 1 DAY
    -> DO
    -> BEGIN
    -> DECLARE log_file VARCHAR(255);
    -> SET log_file = CONCAT('/var/log/sync_db_log_' ,DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y%m%d%H%i%S'));
    -> SELECT * INTO OUTFILE log_file from sync_logger;
    -> DELETE FROM sync_logger;
    -> END;
    -> !!
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'log_file from sync_logger;
DELETE FROM sync_logger;
END' at line 8
MariaDB [sync]> delimiter ;
```

I can't figure out what the problem is. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name of output file is a literal, not a parameter, and it won't be replaced with variable value. Also the filename must be quoted.

Use prepared statement:

```sql
CREATE EVENT IF NOT EXISTS write_to_log_event
ON SCHEDULE
EVERY 1 DAY
DO
BEGIN
SET @write_to_log_event_sql := CONCAT('SELECT * INTO OUTFILE ''/var/log/sync_db_log_' ,
                                      DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y%m%d%H%i%S'), 
                                      ''' FROM sync_logger');
-- SELECT @write_to_log_event_sql; -- for debugging purposes
PREPARE stmt FROM @write_to_log_event_sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DROP PREPARE stmt;
TRUNCATE sync_logger;
END
```

PS. TRUNCATE is faster than DELETE.